# Empty regular expression in sed script

Tags: shell, unix, sed, ksh

Found the following sed script to reverse characters in each line, from the famous "sed one liners", and I am not able to follow the following command in **//D** of the script

```
sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'
```

Suppose the inital file had two lines to start with say,

```
apple
banana
```

After the first command,

```
/\n/!G
```

pattern space would be,

```
apple

banana
```

[a new line introduced after each line. Code tag removing the last new line here. So it is not shown].
After the second command,

```
s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/
```

pattern space would be,

```
apple
pple
a
banana
anana
b
```

How does the third command work after this? Also, I understand [empty regular expression(//)](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html) matches the previously matched regexp. But in this case, what that will be? \n from the 1st command or the regexp substituted by the 2nd command? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest 2 edits: in the script at the top replace `;` with newline so that each command is on a separate line, that makes it much clearer. In the intermediate states after each command show newlines embedded in the pattern space as `¶` to distinguish them from newlines already present in the input (would also solve the Code tag problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the suggestion from [my own comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136436/empty-regular-expression-in-sed-script#comment24801087_17136436)
this is what happens:

After `/\n/!G` pattern space would be

```
apple¶
banana¶
```

After `s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/` pattern space would be

```
apple¶pple¶a
banana¶anana¶b
```

then comes the D command. from `man sed`:

```
   D      Delete  up  to  the first embedded newline in the pattern space.
          Start next cycle, but skip reading from the input  if  there  is
          still data in the pattern space.
```

so the first word and the first `¶` is deleted. then sed starts from the
1st command but since the pattern space contains a `¶` the pattern `/\n/`
does not match and the G command is not executed.
The 2nd command leads to

```
pple¶ple¶pa
anana¶nana¶ab
```

can you continue from there?

Comment: And the `//` address before `D` ?

Comment: @user829755: Neato. Thanks for the explanation. I was wondering why bother with /\n/ for G in the first command. This explains it clearly.

Comment: @captcha: // will take (.)(.*\n) to match from 2nd command. This makes sense as it is in line with the user829755's explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`D` mean Delete first line (until first \n) and restart the current cycle if there is still something in the buffer
`//`  is a shortcut to previous pattern matching (reuse the last pattern to serach for)

```
$ echo "123" | sed -n 's/2/other/;// p'
$
```

No corresponding (because it change the pattern matching content)

```
$ echo "123" | sed -n 's/.2/&still/;// p'
12still3
$
```

Pattern `.2` is found also when `// p` is used because it is the equivalent to `/.2/ p`